# How do I set a custom colour for a category in awful.hotkeys_popup?

Tags: awesome-wm

Each category/tag in awful.hotkeys_popup has a different colour (which is set randomly, I believe).

Is it possible to set the colour manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hotkeys_popup.add_group_rules("awesome", { color = "#fF0000" })
```

Comment: Should this be added in `rc.lua`?

Comment: Yes. Just below the `hotkeys_popup.add_hotkeys()` rule